# Primary / secondary Switch accounts

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-account

My wife and I both own Switches.  My account is set up on both Switches to purchase things.  My account on my Switch is considered the primary and on my wife's Switch it's considered the secondary.  I understand the rules for who can run what on primary and secondary Switches.

The problem is with new Animal Crossing DLC.  We have two Animal Crossing cartridges (so we can play together).  I purchased and downloaded the DLC on my Switch and downloaded it to my wife's Switch.  My wife must be online to access the DLC on her Switch.  I understand that this is how it is supposed to work.

This is a problem during the day as we only have one available network connection which I use for work.  She can't use the DLC on her island on her Switch.  We do not use wi-fi.

MY QUESTION:  If I make it possible for my wife to purchase things on her Switch and she purchases the DLC, will this remove the you-must-be-online requirement?

In my head it will work:  her Switch will be considered the primary for her account and (based on the rules), everybody will be able to access the DLC (like they can do on my Switch--my daughter accesses my island from her account on my Switch).

Comment: I can't really answer the question, but have you considered exchanging primary consoles? That is, make your Switch your wife's Primary Console, and make her Switch your own Primary Console? Also, I recommend making a separate account for your daughter for the day your daughter will want her own account (such as when she becomes an adult). Splitting accounts is, as far as I know, not possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will just reverse the problem--she'll be able to access the DLC whenever she wants, but I'll have to be connected to the internet to access it.  

For what it's worth, everybody has their own users on each Switch.  So, I'll be able to migrate them if more Switches are purchased in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my wife's Switch I set up her user with a Nintendo account.  I then verified that the Nintendo account had her Switch flagged as the primary.  Finally, I purchased the Animal Crossing DLC with her account.  She can now access the new DLC without being connected to the internet.

Comment: If this actually solves your problem, accept it to help future users with the same question

Answer (score 0):

That is how it should work, yes. If you purchase the DLC on her own account/Switch, it should allow her to play without the online requirement. Likewise, if you activate her Switch console as primary for YOUR account, she should be able to do the same while you'll need to have a network connection in order to access it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).